# Change width of TABLE based on its TD cells

Tags: html, css, html-table

I am looking for a way to specify a table's width by specifying widths of its TDs.

In the following scenario ([try it live on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rBec2/1/)) you can see that I have specified width of each TD as **100px** and I expected to get a **300px** table (and a horizontal scrollbar for div) but in practice browsers give them a width of 63px (that's table's width divided by 3)

[image: wrong width]

Is there any way to make TDs determine the width of table and not other way round? So far I have tried different values of table-layout, display, overflow for TD and TABLE without any success.

The html:

```html
<div>
    200px
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>100px</td>
            <td>100px</td>
            <td>100px</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

and a minimal CSS:

```css
div {
    width: 200px; 
    height: 300px; 
    border: solid 1px red; 

    overflow-x: scroll;
}

td {
    width:100px; 
    border: solid 1px #000;
}

table { 
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

Comment: "I am looking for a way to specify a table's width by specifying widths of its TDs."  May I ask why?  Perhaps there's another solution to your problem.

Comment: The table is generated dynamically. Only cell size is known. Table must extend beyond its container boundaries and we should see a scroll bar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simplest solution appears to be setting `min-width` instead of `width` for TDs.

Comment: This works. Just make sure you don't have any width 100% items inside the td (like a div), or else the cell expands to be the full width of the table.

Comment: @meub: Wouldn't setting both `min-width` and `max-width` solve that problem?

Answer (score 3):

A simple solution is make the td's content be 100px wide.

```
<div>
    200px
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td><div class="content">100px</div></td>
            <td><div class="content">100px</div></td>
            <td><div class="content">100px</div></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>

.content {
    width: 100px;
}
```

Comment: I was just about to post that.

Comment: that may work but I found another solution which is purely css based. Thank you though.

Answer (score 0):

If you're dynamically generating the table, you could just dynamically set the width of the table while you're at it. Just calculate the desired width, and add `style="width:300px;"` (or whatever) to the `<table>` tag.

Not that the other options people have posted here aren't also perfectly valid, of course.